# How do I implement progressbar in appindicator?

Tags: application-development, quickly

How do I implement progressbar in appindicator? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress bars are by design **not supported** in app indicators, but they are in Unity Launcher icons.

- Check out the [Launcher integration documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/launcher/) for the details.
- Watch the [Unity integration workshop](http://youtu.be/wqGfsgz1Sl4)

Answer (score 0):

[edit] sorry you said appindicator.  I don't think that was covered.  progressbar in the app icon was.

Have a look here, http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/workshops/  I think it is in the Unity Integration Overview that it was covered.